# Why does it seem like Chrome waits for DOM before executing Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I am scratching my head trying to figure out why my scripts aren't executed in the order indicated in my HTML. I am testing with a simple setup where I load needed stylesheets (jquery-ui is asynchronous) and then immediately issue an alert:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <link rel=preload href=https://ajax.googleapis.com/.../jquery-ui.min.css as=style
        onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <noscript><link rel=stylesheet href=https://ajax.googleapis.com/.../jquery-ui.min.css></noscript>
    <link href=...bootstrapcdn.com/.../bootstrap.min.css rel=stylesheet>
    <link rel=stylesheet href=/static/styles/main.css?584e14ae>
    <link rel=icon type=image/png sizes=32x32 href=/static/media/favicon-32x32.png>
    <link rel=icon type=image/png sizes=16x16 href=/static/media/favicon-16x16.png>
    <link rel=manifest href=/static/media/site.webmanifest>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        alert('I am alertful!')
    </script>
    <!-- My main content lives here -->
    <script defer src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/.../jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="...bootstrapcdn.com/.../bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/mainopen.js?0b85ab7e"></script>
</body>
```

However, I don't see the alert immediately. Instead, it seems to wait until every single source is completely loaded (including those just before `</body>`) before showing the alert. This is seen in this screenshot -- notice how most of the resources listed there aren't in the head tag.

[Screenshot of Dev network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmzZW.png)

The DOMContentLoaded event fires immediately after closing the alert. Why does Chrome load everything before parsing scripts? (Edge does not seem to do this) Is there a way to better control the ordering of things? Any light shed on this situation would be much appreciated!

Context: I would like to start an extremely slow Ajax load as soon as possible, but can't get any scripts to run before every other source is loaded.

Edit: removed integrity for clarity. Note that all external scripts have crossorigin="anonymous" and integrity, if it's important
Edit2: Added some footer scripts for completion

Comment: that HTML is odd ... `<link ....></noscript>` on at least two occasions ... run the scripts in the `<head>` before the `<link>`s

Comment: It's possible that Chrome is downloading the resources asynchronously while the alert box is open. But it seems very unlikely that Chrome *executes* JavaScript in the wrong order.

Comment: @JaromandaX I think that it just looked that way because of a line return issue (now fixed). The <link> is (I think) properly wrapped in <noscript></noscript> per https://web.dev/preload-critical-assets/

Comment: @D.Pardal That's what I would expect as well -- I just can't figure out _why_, for example, Chrome seems to wait for the very last external resource in the HTML to be loaded before executing an inline script I have right before the end of body. It seems like I have no control over what order things happen in until the DOM is all set.

Comment: Chrome probably loads everything in `<head>` before processing anything in `<body>` to avoid [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).